# Color selection based on a function for Highchart graphs?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for graphing and I have a set of colors I want to use for the graphs. I am currently using the **colors** property which solves most of the problem. My issue is that across different kinds of graphs, I would like to have Highcharts use the same color when drawing the representation of a certain key, value pair ie if I have multiple pie charts that show the amount of fruit purchased in a given day. I would like to have Highcharts always use red when "Apple" is the label. Is there anyway to do this with the current API or maybe with a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, so I decided to roll my own function:

```
// Get data
var data = giveMeData(); // At this point the data is already formatted for HC

// Convert data
var convertedData = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i]; 
    item['color'] = pickColor(item.name);
    convertedData.push(item);
}

// Pass converted data to HC
...
```

Wish there was some kind of color function that could take in a point or series item, but this handles my problem for now. If anyone has any better solutions, I'd still love to see them.

Comment: Indeed, there's no such flag to do it automatically - you need to set for each series specific color according to it's name/category/anything.